# I try to paint on a jlayeredpane a sequence of image; i load this images in a class with a for iteration,but the images don't show up

Tags: java, image, swing, paint, jlayeredpane

this is the class who i use to load the images, i use the constructor to call the metod load who load the images in the array percorso.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

class Track extends Component {
   Image[] percorso;
   String path;
   int n;
   int x;
   int y;

   public Track(String path, int n) {
      int i;
      this.path = path;
      this.n = n;
      this.percorso = new Image[n];
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         this.percorso[i] = load(path, n, i);
         repaint();
      }
   }

   public final Image load(String path, int n, int i) {
      Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      String dot = ".jpg";
      path = this.path;
      path = path + Integer.toString(i) + dot;
      Image img = tool.getImage(path);
      try {
         MediaTracker track = new MediaTracker(this);
         track.addImage(img, 0);
         track.waitForID(0);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Image not loaded");
      }
      return (img);
   }

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      int i;
      g.drawImage(percorso[1], x, y, this);
   }
}
```

This is the class where i create the gui, and i try to add the images to the jlayeredpane, but it's didn't work.

```
public class Gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   /** Creates new form GUI */
   public Gui() {
      initComponents();
   }

   /**
    * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
    * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
    * regenerated by the Form Editor.
    */
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
   private void initComponents() {

      background = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
      testata = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      nuova = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      selectrack = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track5.setVisible(false);
      track6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track6.setVisible(false);
      track7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track7.setVisible(false);
      track8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track8.setVisible(false);
      track9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track9.setVisible(false);
      track10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      track10.setVisible(false);
      behind = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      behind.setVisible(false);
      traccy = new javax.swing.JLabel();

      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      testata.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36));
      testata.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      testata.setText("Thosa Racing");
      testata.setBounds(90, 0, 220, 44);
      background.add(testata, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      nuova.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18));
      nuova.setText("Nuova");
      nuova.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            nuovaMouseClicked(evt);
         }
      });
      nuova.setBounds(160, 140, 50, 22);
      background.add(nuova, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      selectrack.setVisible(false);
      selectrack.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      selectrack.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      selectrack.setText("Scegli il tracciato");
      selectrack.setBounds(110, 10, 177, 29);
      background.add(selectrack, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      track1.setVisible(false);
      track1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      track1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      track1.setText("1");
      track1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            track1MouseClicked(evt);
         }
      });
      track1.setBounds(50, 50, 13, 29);
      background.add(track1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      track2.setVisible(false);
      track2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      track2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      track2.setText("2");
      track2.setBounds(120, 50, 13, 29);
      background.add(track2, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      track3.setVisible(false);
      track3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      track3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      track3.setText("3");
      track3.setBounds(190, 50, 13, 29);
      background.add(track3, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      track4.setVisible(false);
      track4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      track4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      track4.setText("4");
      track4.setBounds(250, 50, 13, 29);
      background.add(track4, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      track5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      track5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      track5.setText("5");
      track5.setBounds(320, 50, 13, 29);
      background.add(track5, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      track6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      track6.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      track6.setText("6");
      track6.setBounds(50, 110, 13, 29);
      background.add(track6, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      track7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      track7.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      track7.setText("7");
      track7.setBounds(120, 110, 13, 29);
      background.add(track7, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      track8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      track8.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      track8.setText("8");
      track8.setBounds(190, 110, 13, 29);
      background.add(track8, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      track9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      track9.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      track9.setText("9");
      track9.setBounds(250, 110, 13, 29);
      background.add(track9, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      track10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
      track10.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      track10.setText("10");
      track10.setBounds(320, 110, 26, 29);
      background.add(track10, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      behind.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18));
      behind.setText("Behind");
      behind.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            behindMouseClicked(evt);
         }
      });
      behind.setBounds(10, 260, 54, 22);
      background.add(behind, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
      traccy.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300);
      background.add(traccy, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(background,
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE));
      layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(background,
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE));

      pack();
   }// </editor-fold>

   private void nuovaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
      // Disabilita menu principale
      byte d = 1;
      disable(d);
   }

   private void behindMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
      // Torna al menu principale
      byte d = 2;
      disable(d);
   }

   private void track1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
      trackMDisable(false);
      Track tracciato1 = new Track("src/track/m", 5);
      background.add(tracciato1);

   }

   // Metodo dis/able menu
   public void disable(byte i) {
      boolean d = false;
      switch (i) {
      case 1: {
         // Dal menu principale alla lista tracciati
         d = true;
         principalMDisable(d);
         trackMDisable(d);
      }
      case 2: {
         // Dalla lista tracciati al menu principale
         trackMDisable(d);
         principalMDisable(d);
      }
      }
   }

   public void principalMDisable(Boolean b) {
      if (b == true) {
         // se vero disable il menu principale
         testata.setVisible(false);
         nuova.setVisible(false);
      } else {
         // se falso able il menu principale
         testata.setVisible(true);
         nuova.setVisible(true);
      }
   }

   public void trackMDisable(Boolean b) {
      if (b == true) {
         // se vero able la lista dei tracciati
         selectrack.setVisible(true);
         track1.setVisible(true);
         track2.setVisible(true);
         track3.setVisible(true);
         track4.setVisible(true);
         track5.setVisible(true);
         track6.setVisible(true);
         track7.setVisible(true);
         track8.setVisible(true);
         track9.setVisible(true);
         track10.setVisible(true);
         behind.setVisible(true);
      } else {
         // se falso disable la lista dei tracciati
         selectrack.setVisible(false);
         track1.setVisible(false);
         track2.setVisible(false);
         track3.setVisible(false);
         track4.setVisible(false);
         track5.setVisible(false);
         track6.setVisible(false);
         track7.setVisible(false);
         track8.setVisible(false);
         track9.setVisible(false);
         track10.setVisible(false);
         behind.setVisible(false);
      }
   }

   // Variables declaration - do not modify
   private javax.swing.JLayeredPane background;
   private javax.swing.JLabel behind;
   private javax.swing.JLabel nuova;
   private javax.swing.JLabel selectrack;
   private javax.swing.JLabel testata;
   private javax.swing.JLabel traccy;
   private javax.swing.JLabel track1;
   private javax.swing.JLabel track10;
   private javax.swing.JLabel track2;
   private javax.swing.JLabel track3;
   private javax.swing.JLabel track4;
   private javax.swing.JLabel track5;
   private javax.swing.JLabel track6;
   private javax.swing.JLabel track7;
   private javax.swing.JLabel track8;
   private javax.swing.JLabel track9;
   // End of variables declaration}
}
```

i don't receive any compiler error, i think the error is in the Gui class where i add the images, in the metod track1MouseClicked, i use the JFrom plugin of NetBeans 7.01 for create the frame and company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't gone through all of your code, but this will cause problems:

```
public final Image load(String path, int n, int i) {
  Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  String dot = ".jpg";

  path = this.path; // *****
```

Since you don't really set the path field here. You'll want to reverse that line.

More importantly, you'll want to try to solve your problem in a much smaller simpler program first, a test program that does nothing but read in a bunch of images and displays them, but does nothing else. Then once you have that solved use the code in your larger program. The other benefit is that if your smaller program doesn't work, you can then post it here as a more reasonably sized program that more folks will be willing to read, analyze, test and correct.

Also, don't mix AWT components such as `Component` with Swing components unless absolutely necessary -- which isn't the case with your program.

Comment: i used  




path = this.path;



for delete the last full path and then rewrite with the path without the name of the file, e then add the full path with




path = path + Integer.toString(i) + dot;

thanks a lot

Comment: @Sabum: I don't understand what you just said. Is your program now working?

Comment: not, but yes, if i create a new frame with anythings and add the object tracciato1 the images appear, in other manner don't work